# IOS - Cordova UX change language

Tags: ios, cordova, translation, user-experience

I am here to to ask something about the IOS UX.

I have an app entirely in French, not to be translated in any other language. But my problem is that we use one or two confirm windows.

Even if the content is in French, the rest isn't. We have "OK" "Cancel" or "Accept" "Decline"

I would like to know where and what I need to change so this is in French. I followed some tutorials, telling me to change the language in the -info.plist file, but nothing changed. I selected the French language basically everywhere I could select a language, but same results. Do I need to create a file and put French translations?

Thank you for your help !

Here is my config file (I just removed some stuff like some names)

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
```

app name
    
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    
    
        Apache Cordova Team
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
        
    
    
        
        
        
    
    
    
    -->
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
            
    
    
        need camera access to take pictures
    
    
        need photo library access to get pictures from there
    
    
        
            French
        
    
    
        
            fr_FR

[image: the language in the project's general info]

[image: info.plist]

Comment: Paste your config

Comment: I'll do it as soon as I can, just need to access the mac

Comment: What language is your iOS set to? In a regular web app, language of replaced contents like form controls, especially `<input type="file">`, `<input type="date">` and alerts fired by the browser will use the browser’s language, which is usually the operating system’s language. And that’s ok, no need to change that.

Comment: The app is generated with cordova, the language is in Objective-C. The language is set to French. Other apps have the confirm or other set in French, I don't know why this one isn't.